# отображение 3D-объекта на странице. Django

Tags: python, django, 3d

Как отобразить 3d-объект на странице Django сайта? Пробовал через model-viewer, не работает.

index.html

```html
    <DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="module" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/model-viewer/3.4.0/model-viewer.min.js"></script>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <model-viewer src="{% static '/models/3d-model.stl' %}" shadow-intensity="1" camera-controls touch-action="pan-y" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></model-viewer>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```